# Excel sheet export exception in POI-3.5-beta.jar in android

Tags: android, excel, apache-poi, hssf

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
```

//when initialize this got exception.

```
 HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
```

//And exception is this.

```
05-03 12:32:12.803 27227-27227/com.mindtech.mindcubecanvas W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41c1dc08)
05-03 12:32:12.803 27227-27227/com.mindtech.mindcubecanvas W/System.err: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.poi.util.POILogFactory
05-03 12:32:12.803 27227-27227/com.mindtech.mindcubecanvas W/System.err:     at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<clinit>(HSSFWorkbook.java:156)
05-03 12:32:12.803 27227-27227/com.mindtech.mindcubecanvas W/System.err:     at com.mindtech.mindcubecanvas.ReadInventory.saveExcelFile(ReadInventory.java:2006)
05-03 12:32:12.803 27227-27227/com.mindtech.mindcubecanvas W/System.err:     at com.mindtech.mindcubecanvas.ReadInventory$4$4.onClick(ReadInventory.java:475)
05-03 12:32:12.803 27227-27227/com.mindtech.mindcubecanvas W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4653)
05-03 12:32:12.803 27227-27227/com.mindtech.mindcubecanvas W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19294)
05-03 12:32:12.803 27227-27227/com.mindtech.mindcubecanvas W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-03 12:32:12.803 27227-27227/com.mindtech.mindcubecanvas W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-03 12:32:12.803 27227-27227/com.mindtech.mindcubecanvas W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
05-03 12:32:12.803 27227-27227/com.mindtech.mindcubecanvas W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5603)
05-03 12:32:12.803 27227-27227/com.mindtech.mindcubecanvas W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-03 12:32:12.803 27227-27227/com.mindtech.mindcubecanvas W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-03 12:32:12.803 27227-27227/com.mindtech.mindcubecanvas W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
05-03 12:32:12.803 27227-27227/com.mindtech.mindcubecanvas W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
05-03 12:32:12.803 27227-27227/com.mindtech.mindcubecanvas W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

// i try other jar file of poi but can not resolve.

Comment: which file you are exporting? .xls or .xlsx?

Comment: filename_xls = filename_xls + ".xls";

Comment: Why are you using such an ancient version of Apache POI? What happens if you upgrade to a more recent version?

Comment: i used poi-3.13-20150929.jar its work in android API level 23 or upper version but not working in kitkat or lower version, I used same code(Syntax) in previous application that was work, But now it throw exception.

Comment: Even if you use the older version, why beta version?